# Eclipse with Tomcat $$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ 'Unable to install breakpoint'

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, cglib

I'm aware several people have asked very similar questions to this one, but I really need help finding the solution to my particular case.

Please read and understand this question before posting an answer :)

I'm using 
Eclipse (both Juno and Kepler)
JDK 1.7
Tomcat 7
the Sysdeo Tomcat plugin

and in one particular project (other projects are fine), the following happens:

1. I set a breakpoint
2. start Tomcat
3. execution arrives at that point

I get a message: "Unable to install breakpoint on com.foo.bar.Main.class due to missing line number attributes"  Reason: Absent Line Number Information

The thing is, if it can't install a break point - why is it stopping at exactly that point in the code where I set the breakpoint?  Also, it says line number information is missing but I've verified all Compiler options and even used `javap` to confirm that line number information is in the compiled Main class file.

Note:

- I am not using Ant to build
- I am using the 1.7 JDK in Eclipse (not JRE)

Any guidance or suggestions welcomed.

Edit:

Hmm.. further information that may be important. I'm using Spring, and the actual class that Eclipse tells me has no Line Number Information is actually of the form: 'Main$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$87eae52c'
Could it be that a pre-compilation layer is generating classes without line numbers?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your class files in Eclipse class path is not matched with the class files you have in Tomcat webapp folder. There are out of synchronization. 
You can try to deploy newly built war file again.